# Laravel - Azure DNS - Website url issues (url.com works , www.url.com does not)

Tags: php, .htaccess, azure, dns

I'm trying to setup my azure web app and having some issues with DNS and url

This is my htaccess in the root folder :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is my htaccess in the public folder :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

This is my godaddy records :

[image]

My websites works at url.com

but not for :

www.url.com

http://www.url.com

I get this page :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since `www.url.com` points to `site.azurewebistes.net` and not back at `url.com` you need to add `www.url.com` in the **Custom domains** blade for your Web App in the Azure Portal.

You need to tell the Web App that it should answer for `www.url.com` as well.

Or just CNAME `www` to your root instead (i believe you still need to add the `www` to the Custom Domains blade though).